# Displaying the next lines and white spaces in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I use a text area to collect comments from the user. The text area preserves the next line and white space indentation.
While displaying the comment in a `p` tag the next line and white space indentation at the beginning of the line are lost.

I enter the following text in the text area:

```
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
```

The form save preserves the next line in the comment.

I display the comment as:

```
%p #{@user.comment}
```

This displays the following text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
```

How do I display the saved text with correct whitespaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the simple_format helper

```
= simple_format(@user.comment)
```

Comment: I think the %p would be superfluous because simple_format wraps everything in a paragraph even when there is only one paragraph.

Comment: Since P is an inferred-closing tag, it would also show up in the DOM as: <p></p><p>content</p>